# Synpress: cannot move to Metamask notification in CI execution

Tags: javascript, cypress, playwright

When I run the test in my local environment the test passes, but if I run it on CI using docker, I have the error that you can see in the logs:
It seems it cannot move to the Metamask notification.

```
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('.notification #app-content .app') to be visible
  locator resolved to hidden <div class="app os-linux">…</div>
============================================================
```

[image: 1]

Do you know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm maintainer of synpress.

You have to setup `xvfb` and window manager (like `fluxbox` or `xfce4`) to run tests without issues on CI (together with `DISPLAY` env var). If you need more details, take a look at [CI examples](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress/tree/dev/.github/workflows) inside synpress repository.

Thanks,
Jakub.

Comment: I want to run playwright tests that use Metamask in docker. Is that possible without using Cypress?

Comment: Yes, synpress has support for playwright also. You can see examples [here](https://github.com/drptbl/synpress-examples/tree/master/playwright).